# How to use FlagsAttribute enums on breeze in concordance with ko`s checked binding?

Tags: breeze

Enums that are marked with FlagsAttribute are not properly kept on client side. They are always a string, names separated by comma "," 
It should be an array so it would fit nice with ko` checked binding.

Besides it would be much easier to work with them. 
They should be serialzed (coerced) with comma when sent to the server only.

Have anyone found a solution?

Server side

```
[Flags]
public enum Vechicle : short
{
    None = 0,
    Bicycle = 1,
    Motorcycle = 2,
    Car = 4,
    OtherVehicle = 8,
}
```

Breeze, client side:

```
entity.OwnVechicle(["Car", "Bycle"])
entity.OwnVechicle() 
// returns "Car,Bicycle" rather than ["Car", "Bicycle"]
```

When using this `enum` with `ko` `checked` binding it expects to be bound against an array not a string. [see it here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html#example_adding_checkboxes_bound_to_an_array)

The problem is that Breeze is always enforcing the values to be a concatenated string!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Could you clarify?

Comment: Just added more details on the question